# Replacing outliers with zeroes in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

I want to write function outliers_std(table, std) which replace outliers with zeroes.

Let's define outlier as a variable that satisfies following inequality :

[image]

So I want to go through whole table and if any element satisfies inequality above I want to replace it by 0.

**My work so far**

```
Function outliers_std(table As Variant, std As Double)
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In [table].Rows
        If Abs(table(row) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(table)) / Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(table) > std Then
            table(row) = 0
        End If
    Next
    outliers_std = table
End Function
```

But when trying to run

```
outliers_std(E10:E14,1)
```

where `E10:E14` is data below

[image]

I get error `#ARG!`

Do you have any idea where is the problem ?

**EDIT**

I ran code

```
Function outliers_std(table As Variant, std As Double) As Variant
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In [table].Rows
        If Abs(row - Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(table)) / Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(table) > std Then
            table(row) = 0
        End If
    Next
    outliers_std = table
End Function
```

And still error stays the same. Did I write something incorrectly ?

Comment: Ohh, I changed that. The problem still occurs

Comment: Updated my question ;))

Comment: `row` is now a range in itself.  you would call it with `row` and not `table(row)`  also table should be a 1 column reference.  So `table As Range`

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if I understand. Could you please extend this in answer ?

Comment: `Abs(row - ....`

Comment: `outliers_std = table` won't do what you think if you take this approach either... store the value of `table` in a temporary array.

Comment: And then you would need Set for the return line if table is range which messes with what I think you intend _outliers_std_ to be as a type

Comment: ^^^^ So use an array variable here ^^^.

Comment: ^^ yes and I think intended to be 1D array for input (?) which would mean converting from 2D array read in from sheet to 1D

Comment: Yes, array which I want is with one column and with multiple rows

Comment: I adjusted my question with your tips but it's still not working for me. Is there anything I didn't include ?

Comment: You don't need to declare table inside function (especially not as range as it will be an array) as it is passed as a param. It also needs to be 1D not 2D.

Comment: If you were running this as a UDF (called from a worksheet) then one issue is you can't update the sheet from within the function - it can only return a value (or array of values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code:

```
Function outliers_std(table As Range, std As Double)
    Dim temp() As Variant
    temp = table.Value
    
    Dim mean As Double
    mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(temp)
    
    Dim stdv As Double
    stdv = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(temp)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(temp, 1)
        If Abs(temp(i, 1) - mean) / stdv > std Then
            temp(i, 1) = 0
        End If
    Next
    outliers_std = temp
End Function
```

Now depending on your version one can either put this in one cell and it will spill the results, or they will need to higlight the same number of cells as the table and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to return all the values.

[image]

---

But one does not vba for this if doing it in the worksheet:

```
=IF(ABS(E10:E14-AVERAGE(E10:E14))/STDEV(E10:E14)>1,0,E10:E14)
```

Like above depending on one's version it will auto spill or one will need to highlight the same number of cells and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter

[image]

Comment: The edit is great. I figured that VBA was overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with the original code. One, the value for table cannot but updated. Two, i is never incremented.  I got this code to work.

```
Function outliers_std(table As Variant, std As Double)
Dim i As Integer
Dim row As Range
Dim newtable As Variant

i = 1
ReDim newtable(1 To [table].Rows.Count, 1 To 1) As Variant
For i = 1 To [table].Rows.Count
    If Abs(table(i, 1) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(table)) / Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(table) > std Then
        newtable(i, 1) = 0
    Else
        newtable(i, 1) = table(i)
    End If
Next
outliers_std = newtable
```

End Function

Comment: You need to calculate the mean/stdev before entering the loop...

Comment: Thanks, that certainly would be more efficient computationally.

Comment: It's not just for efficiency - every time you replace a number with a zero it changes the mean and standard deviation, so the cutoff would shift and produce unwanted results.

Comment: It changes the values in newtable and calculates the mean/stdev on table so that should be an issue,  That said it's better to calculate it ahead of time.